# How to open forms ussing keyboard keys

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

I would like to be able to press shift+D+A+L to open another form (form2) ussing VB.net how do i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the forms KeyPreview property to true, then add code to the forms KeyDown event. Y
Then use an if statement e.g 
If e.KeyCode = Keys.F1 Then

Add each key you want as a condition and since you want to use shift add this to your if;
e.modifier = keys.shift

Then create a new instance of the second form and call the showdialog function.